# IAP product in review status cannot delete

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

My app was rejected by apple again, I really don't know how to solve the problem.

I created some IAP products to test in-app-purchase functionality when developed application, finally we decides no charged products available in the current version.

I forgot to delete the products when submit app to app store, and the products are in review status, I found no way to delete the products. I also tried to reject my application, but no manage your in-app-purchase section is available in the app detail view(exited during developing).

Status of product:
[image: status]

Rejection Description:
[image: Rejection]

any solution?

Best Regard

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you manage to find a solution?